# SharePoint Versioning restriction & customize

Tags: sharepoint-2007, versioning, sharepoint-list

With regards to SharePoint 2007 versioning feature:

1. Is it possible to put restriction on who can delete the version of a changed item in a SharePoint List?
2. Can the versioning be apply to new item?
   Example: Suppose there are 3 items created inside a SharePoint List, it will be called Version 1. Later, someone add 5 new items into a SharePoint List, this will result in Version 2. So, if the admin notice that the 5 new items are invalid entry, it can simply delete Version 2.
3. Is it possible to delete certain version for a particular item in a SharePoint List?

Comment: Best place to post non-programming SharePoint questions: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Marek, Have post the questions to sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Don't edit your question to completely change it.  Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. You can customize or create new permission roles (ex. you can customize the contribute role to disallow deleteing items)  See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/manage-permission-levels-HA010117209.aspx
2. Versioning is applied on a per-item basis.  So, in your example, each Item would be at version 1 when uploaded.  Suppose an item is edited, then checked in and published as a major version.  That item is now version 2 while the other items are still version 1.  Batch deletes based on version like you suggest is pointless.  Instead, just delete the items individually.
3. Yes.  See the answer to #1.  One of the customizable abilities is the ability to delete versions.

Comment: answer noted in sharepoint.stackexchange.com;